Asynchronous Http Request Jmeter
Initiate HTTP Request 1:
Thread Group 1 starts sending Request 1 at a rate of 0.3 TPS.
Using the Inter-Thread Communication PreProcessor
Signal Next Step: Once a Request 1 is successfully ended, a signal is sent to Thread Group 2.
Simulate HTTP Request 2:
Thread Group 2, after receiving the signal, waits for 10 seconds and sends Request 2
Currently the output of the test plan do not send Http Request 2 for each Http Request 1


If you want to run requests with different rates you need to put them under different Thread Groups.
To run one request at fixed rate of 0.3 TPS you need to go for Throughput Shaping Timer or Precise Throughput Timer
In order to delay 2nd request until first one is executed you can go for Inter-Thread Communication Plugin

I have tried using the Inter-Thread Communication Plugin, but the 2nd request does not seem to run for each request 1

With the Inter-Threa Communication Plugin, i took the lastRequestTime and add a preprocessor to get the lastrequestTime and set a delay.
Thanks for suggesting this plugin
